# Javascript code is getting executed even before user presses ok on alert window

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, alert

I need to remove video element, Canvas and a button on canvas before displaying an alert window and once user presses ok button on the alert window, I need to display some other elements. Currently I am facing below issues.

1. alert window is getting displayed before deleting the button. So we
   just used `setTimeout` to delete all the elements before displaying
   alert window to fix this.
2. The UI code which should be executed after user presses 'ok' button
   is getting executed after alert window display with out stopping for
   user click. I thought that the code next to `alert()` should not be
   executed until user presses Ok on alert window.

Below is Javascript code.

```
$("#remoteVideo").remove();
$("#localCanvas").remove();
$(".terminate_session_btn").remove();

// USED setTimeout TO DELAY THE DISPLAY OF ALERT WINDOW. WITHOUT
// setTimeout, ALERT WINDOW IS GETTING DISPLAYED BEFORE DELETING THE BUTTON.
setTimeout(function() {
    displayAndProcessUserTerminateAlertDialog();
}, 200);

function displayAndProcessUserTerminateAlertDialog() {
    socket.close();
    alert("User terminated the video call. Press 'Ok' button to create new session.");

    // BELOW CODE IS GETTING EXECUTED WITHOUT STOPPING FOR USER ACTION ON ALERT WINDOW.
    $(".main_container .item").hide();
    $("#video-session-menu").removeClass("active");
    $("#images-menu").removeClass("active");
    $(".sidebar ul li a").addClass("disabled");
}
```

Can anyone please help me to understand why code execution is not stopped until user presses OK on alert window and how to fix this issue.

**UPDATE:**

Interesting thing is if I open developer tools, the issue is not happening. If I don't open developer tools, issue is happening always. I am not sure how to fix this issue.

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: I am using Chrome.

Comment: The behavior you mentioned does not reproduce in my Chrome.

Comment: Ok. I am using Chrome Version 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit). Not sure why the issue is not reproduced in your Chrome browser.

Comment: Is it reproducing for you if you run ```alert(1);console.log(2);```

Comment: Interesting issue is if I open developer tools, the issue is not happening. If I don't open developer tools, issue is happening always.

Comment: I encourage you to create a JSFiddle with a simplified, reproducible version of your problem. I will take a look tomorrow if it's still unsolved at that point.

Comment: @LajosArpad : Thank you. I created simple program with one log before alert and one log after alert. When I tested using jsfddle, both logs are getting printed after I press Ok on alert window. Really strange. JsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/adinakr/gjL51ykv/

Comment: I can reproduce it in Chrome. In FireFox it behaves as expected.

Comment: Yes. Not sure why chrome is not behaving as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently browsers do not have a standard behavior for alert. As a result, you might want to implement your own alert with the behavior you prefer. You can test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/rf0jd7te/1/

## HTML

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Alert Window</p>
    <p>
    <input type="button" value="OK">
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

## CSS

```
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS

```
console.log("before alert");
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = modal.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
// Get the OK element that closes the modal
var OK = modal.querySelector("input[type=button]");
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
function close() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  console.log("after alert");
}
OK.onclick = span.onclick = function() {
  close();
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    close();
  }
}
modal.style.display = "block";
```

Comment: Thanks Lajos. If you have time, could you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63122034/mouseenter-and-mouseleave-elements-are-getting-fired-for-canvas-if-a-button-is-o

Answer (score 1):

2. Alert in JS is only responsible for showing message, try to use [window.confirm(message)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) (check example use case)

Comment: I want to give the user only "Ok" option. Not 'Cancel' option.

Comment: I didn't understand the answer. User doesn't have any option other than pressing Ok. Then why do I need to display confirm window here with Cancel option. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think that in this case neither 'alert' nor 'confirm' will work. If u can use other modal e.g. from bootstrap that should resolve both your issues.

Comment: You can also try to add timeout on code after 'alert' If you are not worried about code quality.

Comment: No. This is not about delay, right? How much time I can give for setTimeout.

Comment: I think that's because of JavaScript code execution order, adding timeouts to delay alert isn't a right way. I'm not an expert in that area yet, so I may be wrong. I've created some example code that may help you: https://codepen.io/rauboluk/pen/mdVgxQZ